# Newly installed Arch Linux canoot boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub

I've installed Arch Linux following the Installation guide but failed to boot.

I've changed the boot order but it skipped the disk I installed Linux without error left.(I have 2 disks and one for Windows and one for Arch)

I've checked the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and menuentry for Arch has been written.

I installed Arch in one disk on 1 single partition.

I'm on BIOS boot. UEFI is disabled.

Thanks for your help!

`fdisk -l` shows [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIbfV.jpg)

Comment: So what happens when you boot? It just goes straight into Windows?

Comment: Yes. And for those who have the same problem, I suggest them to set boot flag as "Linux Lover" mentioned. That's where I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a big question with a lot of potential answers. All I can do is offer some suggestions.

Unless you have a specific reason for only using one parition, going with at least three partitions (/boot, root (/), swap) is more ideal. The swap partition will allow you to hibernate and sleep your computer (you can't without it) and separate root and boot partitions will make repairs waaay easier down the line.

It also appears you are using MBR (dos) and BIOS. Unless your on old hardware that won't support it, using UEFI and GPT is usually preferred. Its the equivalent of old tech vs next gen.

Is secure boot enabled? Have you previously confirmed that the disk will boot Linux properly? Sometimes secure boot or another firmware setting will get in the way and need to be corrected since Arch doesn't sign itself automatically. Thats easy to fix, just take a look at your BIOS settings.

Installing arch can be a huge pain, but there is good news! The whole point of arch is too fail. Failing forces you to learn things you didn't previously know and become a more adept linux user. Good luck with your travels and welcome to the community.

edit: You also may want to try adding the boot flag to the partition via gdisk or parted.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a series of questions and assertions. Given the paucity of information in the question, an actual answer is impossible.

Comment: I am just attempting to help, and at the least educate the asker a little. If you believe more information is needed maybe you should make a comment or an answer stating as such. Sheeeesh

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and it's realy educating! I'm just switching from Ubuntu to Arch and got stuck. Still, I have a few questions about your answer.
1. I used to use boot/root/swap partition but when upgrading softwares my boot partition always full. So I use root/swap partition instead. I'm not sure what do you mean by "make repairs easier". Is there's a particular scanirio for that?
2. I have UEFI on my machine and I am happy to try it later.
3. I've disabled the secure boot and I've installed Ubuntu before in the disk.
4. I'll try adding the boot flag. Hopefully it would work...

Comment: Also, if more information should be given, I 'm happy to offer. That's true that failing teaches me but I do enjoy learning something new. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to set boot flag and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thats great! I'm super glad it worked! Arch can be a b**tch. How large is your /boot? 550M is reccomended, but I usually just go with 1G just in case.  The bennefit of having /boot on a seperate partition is if you ever need to fully wipe your bootloader and reinstall its waaayy easier. You can just wipe that parition and rebuild. It also makes backups of / more convienient and  makes dual booting easier if you get into that. Have fun with arch man, get Gnome or KDE on their stat and enjoy!!!

Comment: For the record, contrary to what @jasonwryan stated, the information to solve the problem was in the post, evident by the lack of a boot flag on the fdisk printout.